# Windows 8 freezing on a VHD on a MacBookPro

Tags: windows, windows-8-preview, vhd

I've installed Windows 8 on a 2010 MacBook Pro using the Hanselman's method (VHD on native boot). Everything goes fine until it suddenly freezes and I must reboot. I have no log to see and no error to look for it on the web, just frozen.

Did anybody have any similar problem?

Answer (score 2):

I can confirm this issue on a MacBook Pro 13", Mid-2009. In addition, I found [an article](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsdeveloperpreviewgeneral/thread/27a7e81b-a2f7-4fbd-88c6-9f9d0659e2b3/) on MSDN's forums about this exact type of freezing. It's possible the issue is caused by the NVIDIA driver that gets installed by Boot Camp. I downloaded the newest driver for Windows 7 (version 295.73), but it did not resolve the problem.

[This comment thread](http://gigaom.com/apple/how-to-install-windows-8-preview-using-boot-camp/#comment-655950) indicates that uninstalling Boot Camp (or not installing it in the first place) resolves the freezes. I haven't had long enough to confirm this myself, but I'll update this answer if I can confirm it.